# How to install wordpress on main directory and not in sub directory on ubuntu?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install the wordpress on the website which is accessible like this:  domain.com. But when i use following command it is getting installed on following directory:  domain.com/wordpress

```
cp -R wordpress /var/www/html/
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wordpress/
mkdir /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
```

I try to remove wordpress but then it tells me on 4rd command that the wordpress doens't exist

Comment: Assuming that you are using apache, you should look into virtual hosts, for instance https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-apache2-virtualhost-multiple-wordpress-blogs/

Comment: @Nk nk nk I saw you got it working. Was my answer helpful to you? Please consider upvoting and marking my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Only copy the **contents** of the `wordpress` directory to `/var/www/html`, not the entire directory.

```
cp -a wordpress/. /var/www/html/
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Comment: So, i must only change first command like this: cp -a wordpress/. /var/www/html/
. And evry next command must i leave as it is now?

Comment: Yes indeed. But leave `/wordpress/` out. Also `mkdir /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads` should not be needed to do as WP will make it itself. I added a line, and that really should be enough, no other commands needed if you ask me. Maybe only the `chmod` if file permissions are not correct

Comment: I did so but it doesn work, see please 62.171.147.64

Comment: Is there a file called `index.html` in `/var/www/html`? If so please remove it. Leave `index.php` in place